# Reshape from wide to long, but receiving "Erro: Each variable must have a unique name."

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I'm trying to reshape this sort of dat from wide to long, but I'm consistently receiving an error message. What am I doing wrong?

The following is the command I'm using and next is a snippet of my data.

```
dat <- gather(data, key = "Discriminação", value = "Valor", 2:25)



 data =  structure(list(Discriminação = c("I. RECEITA TOTAL", "I.1 -  Receita Administrada pela RFB", 
"I.1.1    Imposto de Importação", "I.1.2    IPI", "I.1.2.1    IPI - Fumo", 
"I.1.2.2    IPI - Bebidas", "I.1.2.3    IPI - Automóveis", "I.1.2.4    IPI - Vinculado a importação", 
"I.1.2.5    IPI - Outros", "I.1.3    Imposto de Renda", "I.1.3.1  I.R. - Pessoa Física", 
"I.1.3.2  I.R. - Pessoa Jurídica", "I.1.3.3  I.R. - Retido na Fonte", 
"I.1.3.3.1    IRRF - Rendimentos do Trabalho", "I.1.3.3.2    IRRF - Rendimentos do Capital", 
"I.1.3.3.3    IRRF - Remessas ao Exterior", "I.1.3.3.4    IRRF - Outros Rendimentos", 
"I.1.4    IOF", "I.1.5    COFINS", "I.1.6    PIS/PASEP", "I.1.7    CSLL", 
"I.1.8    CPMF", "I.1.9    CIDE  Combustíveis", "I.1.10  Outras", 
"I.2 -  Incentivos Fiscais", "I.3 -  Arrecadação Líquida para o RGPS", 
"I.3.1    Urbana", "I.3.2    Rural", "I.4 -  Receitas Não Administradas pela RFB", 
"I.4.1  Concessões e Permissões", "I.4.2  Dividendos e Participações", 
"I.4.3  Contr. Plano de Seguridade Social do Servidor", "I.4.4  CotaParte de Compensações Financeiras", 
"I.4.5  Receitas Próprias (fontes 50, 81 e 82)", "I.4.6  Contribuição do Salário Educação", 
"I.4.7  Complemento para o FGTS (LC nº 110/01)", "I.4.8  Operações com Ativos", 
"I.4.9  Demais Receitas", "II. TRANSF. POR REPARTIÇÃO DE RECEITA ²", 
"II.1  FPM / FPE / IPI-EE", "II.2  Fundos Constitucionais", "II.2.1  Repasse Total", 
"II.2.2  Superávit dos Fundos", "II.3  Contribuição do Salário Educação", 
"II.4  Compensações Financeiras", "II.5  CIDE - Combustíveis", 
"II.6  Demais ", "III. RECEITA LÍQUIDA  (I-II)"), `35431` = c("12290.48402097", 
"7771.686318", "308.33310599999999", "1154.2698489999998", "239.76640076000001", 
"0", "0", "0", "914.50344823999978", "3078.6463939999999", "94.157627899999994", 
"746.44417759999999", "2193.4616628099998", "1021.97845", "933.9063329999999", 
"141.84613899999999", "95.73074081", "286.14657599999998", "1609.839849", 
"633.52791100000013", "566.52460299999996", "0", "0", "134.39803000000001", 
"-43.786000000000001", "3558.9", "n.d.", "n.d.", "1003.6837029700005", 
"0", "1.018E-3", "143.91146118", "0", "0", "219.19327398999999", 
"0", "0", "640.57794980000051", "2501.2770794613334", "2219.0989999999997", 
"142.74600000000001", "n.d.", "n.d.", "116.90307946133339", "0", 
"0", "22.529000000000423", "9789.2069415086662"), `35462` = c("11596.253605349999", 
"7412.7677630000007", "373.71706499999999", "1370.349948", "265.70880774", 
"0", "0", "0", "1104.6411402599999", "2289.4818289999998", "96.123338219999994", 
"878.31575730999998", "1251.9269735099997", "832.32662199999993", 
"217.02893699999998", "98.032178000000002", "104.53923650999977", 
"224.96925100000001", "1484.127166", "593.81305099999997", "487.84078900000003", 
"517.02352699999994", "0", "71.445137000000003", "-54.344999999999999", 
"3328.8999999999996", "n.d.", "n.d.", "908.93084234999878", "0", 
"79.841385000000002", "106.13582145999999", "0", "0", "223.46032242999999", 
"0", "0", "499.49331345999883", "1931.8750075993335", "1699.558", 
"106.44", "n.d.", "n.d.", "119.17883862933338", "0", "0", "6.6981689700000828", 
"9664.378597750665"), `35490` = c("13069.057196370002", "8772.0905360000015", 
"392.20991500000002", "1333.5901859999999", "224.42094527999998", 
"0", "0", "0", "1109.1692407199998", "3109.7138089999999", "88.046134890000005", 
"1602.69746854", "1359.1085645200001", "912.31195400000001", 
"256.197971", "84.837182999999996", "105.76145652000002", "248.65517800000001", 
"1433.108508", "548.6668360000001", "1075.9043630000001", "566.18171600000005", 
"0", "64.06002500000001", "0", "3321.2", "n.d.", "n.d.", "975.76666037000086", 
"0", "43.971899000000001", "105.09224094999998", "0", "0", "220.03384943999998", 
"0", "0", "606.66867098000091", "1770.4347517780002", "1550.672", 
"97.075999999999993", "n.d.", "n.d.", "117.35138636800005", "0", 
"0", "5.3353654100000796", "11298.622444592002"), `35521` = c("13388.171682420005", 
"9102.386582000001", "425.32219399999997", "1359.284204", "238.45872682999999", 
"0", "0", "0", "1120.8254771700001", "3362.6831529999995", "639.58441151", 
"1077.2064527799998", "1572.6546193000001", "1027.6666290000001", 
"329.77585899999997", "103.102914", "112.10921730000024", "292.27561700000001", 
"1535.004101", "590.17022700000007", "811.20736099999999", "668.49842200000001", 
"0", "57.941302999999998", "-29", "3398.1", "n.d.", "n.d.", "916.68510042000389", 
"0", "6.4229659999999997", "134.95704977", "0", "0", "215.71615711000001", 
"0", "0", "559.58892754000385", "2164.2085945553331", "1925.537", 
"121.738", "n.d.", "n.d.", "115.04861712533341", "0", "0", "1.8849774299998217", 
"11223.963087864669"), `35551` = c("12508.213110380002", "8007.4372199999998", 
"382.67831999999999", "1361.4987289999999", "227.75285596999998", 
"0", "0", "0", "1133.74587303", "2629.7056899999998", "330.61697849000001", 
"788.03873327000008", "1449.82330075", "929.57523800000001", 
"280.78663299999999", "117.78514399999999", "121.67628575000002", 
"312.07559699999996", "1581.3016440000001", "608.18087200000002", 
"479.33566099999996", "594.38239399999998", "0", "58.278313000000004", 
"-45", "3473.2309999999998", "n.d.", "n.d.", "1072.5448903800025", 
"0", "232.28614400000001", "126.14749049", "0", "0", "218.42420874999999", 
"0", "0", "495.68704714000251", "2203.5913893333332", "1961.6490000000003", 
"124.236", "n.d.", "n.d.", "116.4929113333334", "0", "0", "1.2134779999995544", 
"10304.621721046669"), `35582` = c("11824.056829910003", "7705.8808960000006", 
"423.258465", "1404.9834140000003", "235.48867934", "0", "0", 
"0", "1169.4947346600002", "2172.5273669999997", "283.86115847000002", 
"869.88687890000006", "950.12790891999998", "421.46072599999997", 
"308.02626100000003", "112.414507", "108.22641492000001", "341.44264300000003", 
"1615.697032", "609.43273999999997", "498.90150299999999", "575.47173999999995", 
"0", "64.165992000000003", "-155.38499999999999", "3473.1", "n.d.", 
"n.d.", "800.46093391000204", "0", "4.4937019999999999", "92.34258797999999", 
"0", "0", "219.36043831000001", "0", "0", "484.26420562000203", 
"1687.9608151974346", "1553.1890000000001", "17.047952182101312", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "116.9922337653334", "0", "0", "0.73162924999984114", 
"10136.096014712566"), `35612` = c("13248.000809469999", "8486.7798770000009", 
"451.13639899999998", "1307.0941879999998", "205.0856119", "0", 
"0", "0", "1102.0085760999998", "2775.5193640000002", "281.91281991", 
"1036.98037765", "1386.13954515", "680.54449199999988", "453.92956500000003", 
"122.309729", "129.35575915000018", "401.24825700000002", "1561.7878549999998", 
"602.17614700000001", "572.1337769999999", "756.63713199999995", 
"0", "59.046757999999997", "-55", "3592.21", "n.d.", "n.d.", 
"1224.0109324699997", "135.4", "134.364631", "124.67114504", 
"0", "0", "206.50295422000002", "0", "0", "623.07220220999966", 
"1830.6459670304512", "1652.61", "64.672273503117964", "n.d.", 
"n.d.", "110.13490891733339", "0", "0", "3.22878460999992", "11417.354842439549"
), `35643` = c("13393.354350400001", "7696.924801000001", "445.56037600000002", 
"1414.2827909999999", "239.13283902000001", "0", "0", "0", "1175.1499519799997", 
"2159.3157150000002", "258.32754231000001", "850.98628030999998", 
"962.61133146999998", "434.42924499999998", "316.82622800000001", 
"88.554198", "122.80166047", "346.66533199999998", "1592.6949499999998", 
"627.44175500000006", "471.95965699999999", "581.04766600000005", 
"0", "57.956559000000006", "-145.59299999999999", "3575.68", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "2266.3425494000007", "1381.2222220000001", "1.8461559999999999", 
"100.41527470000001", "0", "0", "227.72102355999999", "0", "0", 
"555.13787314000047", "1896.733564378198", "1735.5420000000001", 
"36.422213802864533", "n.d.", "n.d.", "121.45121256533339", "0", 
"0", "3.3181380099999558", "11496.620786021802"), `35674` = c("12771.906180679995", 
"8172.117729999999", "456.30073599999997", "1496.796775", "254.93903693999999", 
"0", "0", "0", "1241.85773806", "2394.323832", "260.72712253999998", 
"954.72709888999998", "1078.19987674", "534.580421", "312.35145399999999", 
"118.588047", "112.67995473999999", "349.10860300000002", "1670.110428", 
"650.45497", "522.62379299999998", "577.63895000000002", "0", 
"54.759643000000004", "0", "3646.326", "n.d.", "n.d.", "953.46245067999553", 
"0", "47.531815000000002", "75.947586709999996", "0", "0", "226.17218356000001", 
"0", "0", "603.81086540999559", "1958.5167068121268", "1790.6486545400003", 
"44.919080286793402", "n.d.", "n.d.", "120.62516456533339", "0", 
"0", "2.3238074199998948", "10813.389473867868"), `35704` = c("13497.085229590002", 
"8948.6852589999999", "488.582157", "1398.1782039999998", "206.50459298999999", 
"0", "0", "0", "1191.6736110099998", "2957.9442980000003", "113.77742537", 
"1079.4770321900003", "1706.64245218", "850.165255", "416.97395700000004", 
"296.84378900000002", "142.65945117999999", "405.07523200000003", 
"1651.783981", "645.21165999999994", "606.19046400000002", "718.54235500000004", 
"0", "77.176907999999997", "-60", "3667.1550000000002", "n.d.", 
"n.d.", "941.24497059000214", "0", "65.990613999999994", "94.702495609999986", 
"0", "0", "223.29663748000002", "0", "0", "557.2552235000021", 
"1994.2202348010032", "1829.7845294900003", "42.376053231670284", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "119.0915399893334", "0", "0", "2.9681120899993942", 
"11502.864994788999"), `35735` = c("12991.686654489999", "8542.9044609999983", 
"491.13259999999997", "1506.5236199999999", "249.40052285000002", 
"0", "0", "0", "1257.1230971499999", "2572.6663779999999", "101.30243606000001", 
"775.02217561999998", "1639.9796805200001", "838.34985800000004", 
"523.13488100000006", "163.304834", "115.19010752", "275.934732", 
"1674.904131", "698.08664899999997", "606.70254", "654.10314800000003", 
"0", "62.850663000000004", "-30", "3639.81", "n.d.", "n.d.", 
"838.97219349000034", "0.1", "35.594844999999999", "66.410481389999987", 
"0", "0", "221.62905022999999", "0", "0", "515.23781687000042", 
"2208.9495432265444", "2022.8302456900001", "66.091460943877934", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "118.20216012266673", "0", "0", "1.8256764699997916", 
"10782.737111263456"), `35765` = c("18434.105477189998", "11091.329897", 
"497.02492599999999", "1445.887154", "252.60338658000001", "0", 
"0", "0", "1193.28376742", "4517.476138", "118.61851373", "1553.6552950299999", 
"2692.67334127", "1621.9819199999999", "660.90716099999997", 
"230.42196300000001", "179.36229726999997", "300.42980699999998", 
"1702.6105639999998", "775.21188100000006", "989.49197099999992", 
"699.83304799999996", "0", "163.364408", "-130", "5586.1449999999995", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "1886.6305801899971", "0.47", "170.00148999999999", 
"129.11397820000002", "0", "0", "353.95662580000004", "0", "0", 
"1233.088486189997", "2095.2077072981447", "1859.46607189", "44.97314204481151", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "188.77686709333346", "0", "0", "1.9916262700000402", 
"16338.89776989185"), `35796` = c("15390.441466870003", "10906.728187999999", 
"510.74404200000004", "1194.96523", "241.5020207", "0", "0", 
"0", "953.46320930000002", "5012.6352479999996", "115.06900131", 
"1117.4747719700001", "3712.0042102699999", "1234.072263", "2185.9418620000001", 
"173.76347000000001", "118.22661527", "339.24859900000001", "1615.2497609999998", 
"652.59278400000005", "714.61072799999988", "740.71939499999996", 
"0", "125.962401", "-127.514", "3701.1030000000005", "n.d.", 
"n.d.", "910.12427887000149", "0.48799999999999955", "0.40454600000000002", 
"126.33518565", "0", "0", "208.55596287", "0", "0", "574.34058435000156", 
"2712.2949299640004", "2523.3347943799999", "39.034000000000006", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "111.22984686400005", "0", "0", "38.69628872000024", 
"12678.146536906002"), `35827` = c("13199.191340049998", "9024.2133329999997", 
"412.09669500000001", "1429.5953810000001", "271.21373493999999", 
"0", "0", "0", "1158.3816460600001", "3459.7957259999994", "87.531837190000005", 
"1022.9946357300001", "2286.7400979599997", "1111.0554549999999", 
"930.38229699999999", "130.980435", "114.32191096", "344.51977299999999", 
"1437.4495529999999", "567.04374699999994", "702.27485899999999", 
"595.18275700000004", "0", "76.254841999999996", "-80.305999999999997", 
"3562.4070000000002", "n.d.", "n.d.", "692.87700704999952", "8.9999999999999993E-3", 
"2.6236839999999999", "98.956290799999991", "0", "0", "226.58065503999998", 
"0", "0", "364.70737720999955", "1832.2064870213333", "1672.6220356900001", 
"37.439", "n.d.", "n.d.", "120.84301602133338", "0", "0", "1.3024353099997796", 
"11366.984853028665"), `35855` = c("17814.424200450001", "10507.180350000001", 
"556.83885999999995", "1289.0359209999999", "191.71630832", "0", 
"0", "0", "1097.3196126799999", "4680.9593180000002", "102.51073916", 
"2297.39701212", "2171.3930839099999", "1193.0520549999999", 
"698.44958599999995", "165.79492000000002", "114.09652291", "325.52037000000001", 
"1403.5725430000002", "592.41761300000007", "998.07398899999998", 
"579.60433399999999", "0", "81.157402000000005", "-42.335999999999999", 
"3591.8740000000003", "n.d.", "n.d.", "3757.7058504500005", "2453.0899109999991", 
"8.6000000000000003E-5", "147.64468979", "0", "0", "177.76331181", 
"0", "0", "979.20785185000159", "2710.8970393320005", "2554.4266379299997", 
"51.35199999999999", "n.d.", "n.d.", "94.807099632000046", "0", 
"0", "10.311301770000512", "15103.527161118"), `35886` = c("15669.699987049993", 
"9697.2334009999977", "543.17575299999999", "1384.5818419999998", 
"206.25575233000001", "0", "0", "0", "1178.3260896699999", "3798.6548489999996", 
"731.94820131000006", "1010.5392300899998", "1976.5378851699998", 
"1131.250996", "583.61334599999998", "127.85935900000001", "133.81418416999975", 
"380.929104", "1547.962796", "634.12534000000005", "581.09353999999996", 
"733.48923600000001", "0", "93.220940999999996", "-189.21700000000001", 
"3507.9589999999998", "n.d.", "n.d.", "2653.724586049997", "1588.588086", 
"71.025681000000006", "96.704806160000018", "0", "0", "174.58019000000002", 
"0", "0", "722.82582288999674", "2548.3244588966663", "2418.5344674899998", 
"27.272000000000006", "n.d.", "n.d.", "93.109434666666729", "0", 
"0", "9.4085567399998808", "13121.37552815333"), `35916` = c("13517.95185123", 
"8287.8721819999992", "527.16130199999998", "1382.4197120000001", 
"194.20041621999999", "0", "0", "0", "1188.21929578", "2777.997081", 
"336.04507410999997", "600.85284999999999", "1769.0233771999999", 
"1055.4177319999999", "450.46854500000001", "150.51565199999999", 
"112.6214482", "344.744125", "1586.856053", "588.91645799999992", 
"383.520757", "624.449523", "0", "71.807171000000011", "-15.87", 
"3781.4029999999998", "n.d.", "n.d.", "1464.546669230001", "4.4999999999999998E-2", 
"620.02518599999996", "85.884310259999978", "0", "0", "188.65096781999998", 
"0", "0", "569.94120515000111", "2404.2200649639999", "2245.1003144799993", 
"57.012999999999977", "n.d.", "n.d.", "100.61384950400003", "0", 
"0", "1.4929009800005986", "11113.731786266002"), `35947` = c("12474.79400794", 
"7781.8275079999994", "547.44252399999993", "1405.8066799999999", 
"202.18905785999999", "0", "0", "0", "1203.6176221399999", "2228.9695919999999", 
"304.28720045", "711.52925444000005", "1146.5436723399998", "418.26559699999984", 
"474.34253999999999", "138.20045400000001", "115.73508133999999", 
"319.93960700000002", "1568.9624999999999", "597.44099800000004", 
"428.17352", "608.87003700000002", "0", "76.22205000000001", 
"-4.2290000000000001", "3698.5410000000002", "n.d.", "n.d.", 
"998.65449994000028", "0.127", "14.089185000000001", "99.603259739999999", 
"0", "0", "191.22834881", "0", "0", "693.60670639000023", "1799.9533043886668", 
"1633.1986809599998", "64.704999999999998", "n.d.", "n.d.", "101.98845269866671", 
"0", "0", "6.1170730000426943E-2", "10674.840703551334"), `35977` = c("13744.352905719999", 
"9314.9829399999999", "602.00114299999996", "1301.0499579999998", 
"191.66142134999998", "0", "0", "0", "1109.3885366499999", "3571.6331800000003", 
"291.87405825000002", "1041.6974843400001", "2176.7482178400001", 
"656.95766700000001", "1187.0872080000001", "182.94085100000001", 
"149.76249184", "333.40006599999998", "1538.635389", "593.24546199999997", 
"583.62730299999998", "744.16292399999998", "0", "47.227515000000004", 
"-8.4049999999999994", "3516.94", "n.d.", "n.d.", "920.83496571999922", 
"1.0000000227373675E-8", "1.8897000000000001E-2", "98.918544499999996", 
"0", "0", "180.22764240000001", "0", "0", "641.6698818099992", 
"2002.1530154710001", "1700.2066716500001", "184.12799999999999", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "96.121409280000051", "0", "0", "21.696934540999948", 
"11742.199890249"), `36008` = c("20363.908730990996", "9491.7670990000006", 
"532.44559100000004", "1255.758163", "202.99178824999998", "0", 
"0", "0", "1052.7663747500001", "3343.0776089999995", "276.18249539999999", 
"1022.08258251", "1961.6721877899997", "420.04024099999992", 
"1246.2563829999999", "166.29924700000001", "129.07631678999979", 
"218.80991200000003", "1778.316544", "730.92296799999997", "944.90770600000008", 
"639.83471799999995", "0", "47.693888000000001", "-39.756", "3836.82", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "7075.0776319909965", "5280.5060000000003", "35.319625000000002", 
"100.25867321", "0", "0", "196.93138944999998", "0", "0", "1462.0619443309961", 
"2349.9023974233332", "2181.8995128999995", "61.953000000000003", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "105.03007437333339", "0", "0", "1.0198101500006658", 
"18014.00633356766"), `36039` = c("13435.942530931001", "9043.5347969999984", 
"620.245408", "1281.376839", "189.17177395000002", "0", "0", 
"0", "1092.20506505", "3407.3325839999998", "280.56836007999999", 
"556.81379308999999", "2422.4623104299999", "1027.6085089999999", 
"1028.889269", "206.15454600000001", "159.80998642999998", "250.16541800000002", 
"1555.7040529999999", "608.96577200000002", "414.17261899999994", 
"817.87920399999996", "0", "87.692900000000009", "-90.122", "3656.6120000000001", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "825.91773393100266", "8.9999999999999993E-3", 
"1.2554110000000001", "102.92880083000001", "0", "0", "189.64963", 
"0", "0", "532.07489210100266", "2293.9131594733331", "2119.3795910200001", 
"63.349000000000018", "n.d.", "n.d.", "101.14646933333339", "0", 
"0", "10.038099119999572", "11142.029371457671"), `36069` = c("13112.173313491001", 
"8605.6747770000002", "581.04622000000006", "1262.7125250000001", 
"218.05608486", "0", "0", "0", "1044.6564401400001", "3035.8049339999998", 
"111.58819786000001", "1009.1560925299999", "1855.7209905100001", 
"712.06523600000003", "815.09957099999997", "207.83347499999999", 
"120.72270851000022", "231.51679700000003", "1558.218462", "635.39972299999999", 
"602.15865999999994", "632.05329099999994", "0", "66.764164999999991", 
"-43.186", "3660.4500000000003", "n.d.", "n.d.", "889.2345364910002", 
"1.7999999999999999E-2", "0.73397500000000004", "101.15300791999999", 
"0", "0", "192.68519298000001", "0", "0", "594.64436059100012", 
"1997.6991413460003", "1815.94290972", "66.417000000000002", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "102.76543625600006", "0", "0", "12.573795370000141", 
"11114.474172145001"), `36100` = c("14546.424079400998", "8271.4698059999992", 
"552.079069", "1329.2215070000002", "216.73742215999999", "0", 
"0", "0", "1112.4840848400002", "2915.1926709999998", "97.490908919999995", 
"718.42489679000005", "2049.97595443", "1031.2093519999999", 
"788.53030999999999", "116.21842700000001", "114.01786543", "200.31148099999999", 
"1542.4363979999998", "618.21667400000001", "393.66905400000007", 
"604.80808300000001", "0", "115.534869", "-70.058000000000007", 
"3396.9250000000002", "n.d.", "n.d.", "2948.087273400999", "9.9999818101059656E-10", 
"673.09786199999996", "95.509254430000027", "0", "0", "201.91575975000001", 
"0", "0", "1977.5643972199991", "2088.5287821700003", "1945.0284024399998", 
"27.867999999999995", "n.d.", "n.d.", "107.68840520000006", "9.8328539999999993", 
"0", "-1.8888794699998801", "12457.895297230998"), `36130` = c("20246.899803710003", 
"10819.927981999999", "545.67627000000005", "1307.5069079999998", 
"209.52541955999999", "0", "0", "0", "1097.9814884399998", "4679.404368999999", 
"109.12242667999999", "729.15418846", "3763.7645197899997", "1888.1224129999998", 
"1538.4220789999999", "174.47774799999999", "162.74227978999997", 
"244.74447899999998", "1564.0219519999998", "662.73690399999998", 
"933.86233600000014", "796.99911500000007", "0", "84.975649000000004", 
"-59", "6372.7683211399999", "n.d.", "n.d.", "3113.2035005700018", 
"34.838333949999999", "951.95829967999998", "111.91725922000001", 
"0", "0", "331.04459944000001", "0", "0", "1683.445008280002", 
"2416.2152400913333", "1952.7175891500001", "195.54700000000003", 
"n.d.", "n.d.", "176.55711970133345", "58.419996359999999", "0", 
"32.973534880000088", "17830.684563618666")), .Names = c("Discriminação", 
"35431", "35462", "35490", "35521", "35551", "35582", "35612", 
"35643", "35674", "35704", "35735", "35765", "35796", "35827", 
"35855", "35886", "35916", "35947", "35977", "36008", "36039", 
"36069", "36100", "36130"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Using your example data did not produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've told `gather` to keep the Discriminação column, and also to create a new Discriminação (which will be the column names).

Instead, try:

```
dat <- gather(data, key = "column_names", value = "Valor", 2:25)
```